.NET 6.0 cannot install on a Windows 10 PC
I have a Windows 10 PC.
It currently has these .NET frameworks installed;
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5 Multi Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 Multi Targeting Pack (ENU)
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.1 SDK
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi Targeting Pack
Microsoft .NET Framework 4.5.2 Multi Targeting Pack (ENU)
I'm trying to get a service running on it which I've built on a different PC using .NET 6.0, but it refuses to run with a message of "Could not resolve CoreCLR path. For more details, enable tracing by setting COREHOST_TRACE environment variable to 1"
I figured it's because the machine doesn't have the same version of .NET installed as the development PC had, so I've downloaded and installed the .NET package from Microsoft (https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet/6.0), but after downloading and running the installer (and rebooting), .NET 6.0 does not appear as one of the installed frameworks.
How can I get .NET 6.0 installed on this PC?
I have downloaded and installed .NET 6.0, but even after a reboot, it does not appear as an installed framework.

While publishing your application, in the publish settings you can see two options - Framework Dependent and Portable. Have you tried using the Portable option. The deployment size will be larger in this approach, but you don't need to install .Net 6 in your server.

Thank you for that - that's sorted out the problem!
